# The line of numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have got line of numbers, below.

> 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14 ...

I would like to know their general formula. I mean this (the Gauss ...)

$$a_{n} = a_{1} + d\times(n-1)$$

I do not know how to name it in English. :-) Can you tell me a name of book where I can learn more about this subject? How to find/ make any formulae.

I am not a student and this is not my homework.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like $a_n=a_{n-2}+4$.

Comment: You might want to look up terms like "generating function" and "recursive sequence". But be aware that there is no algorithm (yet...) to give a nice form for any sequence. If you for example come up with one for the sequence of prime numbers, you will get really famous.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. And a name of a mathematical book? :-)

Comment: [these notes](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM2.pdf) might be a good place to start.

Comment: @Bemte Thank you for good ideas.

Comment: There are other possibilities, e.g.,  see [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+5%2C+6%2C+9%2C+10%2C+13%2C+14&language=german&go=Suche): just integers $n\ge 1$ congruent to $1$ or $2$ modulo $4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  That's the same recursion, no?  I mean...your list is the solution of $a_n=a_{n-2}+4$ with $a_0=1,a_1=2$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, it is the same. I wanted to say, that if you say " I have got line of numbers, below",  there are many ways to continue such a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of $$a_n=a_{n-2}+4$$ is $$u+v\cdot (-1)^n+2n$$

Note that the characteristic equation corresponding with the homogenous equation is $x^2-1=0$ with roots $-1$ and $1$, and a special solution of the inhomogenous equation  is $2n$

Inserting $n=1$ and $n=2$ gives $$u-v+2=1$$ $$u+v+4=2$$ with solution $u=-\frac{3}{2}$ , $v=-\frac{1}{2}$

Therefore we have $$a_n=-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{(-1)^n}{2}+2n=\frac{4n-3-(-1)^n}{2}$$

Comment: Wow. Your answer is great.

Answer (score 0):

It is the merging of two Arithmetic progressions of common difference $4$

$1,5,9,13,\dots$
and
$2,6,10,14,\dots$

so $a_{2n+1}=a_{2n-1}+4$
and $a_{2n+2}=a_{2n}+4$ for all $n\geq 1$

Another way is $a_{2n+1}=a_{2n}+3$
and $a_{2n}=a_{2n-1}+1$  $n\geq 1$

Also generally $a_n=a_{n-2}+4$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\left(\frac{3+(-1)^n}{2}\right)+4(\big\lceil \frac{n}{2}\big\rceil-1)$$